# What is the name for the region enclosed by an $n$ dimensional object?

Tags: terminology, dimension-theory-analysis, volume

In a $1$ dimensional object, the name for the region enclosed by it is the **length** of the object. In a $2$ dimensional object, the name for the region is the **area** of the object. In a $3$ dimensional object, the name is the **volume** of the object. What  is the name in a $4$ dimensional object? Hypervolume? In general, what can we call the name of this region in a $n$ dimensional object? ("the region enclosed by this $n$ dimensional object" seems too long and wordy).

Comment: I've seen the term "bulk" used for polychorons, but the general term is indeed "hypervolume".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that just *volume* is actually a fine choice for any dimension $\geq 3$, but if you really want to emphasize the relevant dimension, you could say *$n$-volume* or *$n$-hypervolume*. [Take a look at the Wikipedia page on Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure).

I think good catch-all terms (i.e., for dimensions $1$ and $2$ as well) would be **[measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_%28mathematics%29)** or **[content](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Content.html)**.

Comment: $4$-$volume$ sounds a little strange when said aloud, but I like it.

Comment: Glad I could help :) By the way, to get formatting in text, I suggest using Markdown ([see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)), so that to get $4$-*volume*, you would write `$4$-*volume*`, not `$4$-$volume$`.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about that (but I did use it in the question itself). Also, no wonder why I recognized your username; you were one of the old moderators!

Comment: Ah, I should have noticed, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

How about $n$-volume?  Many objects carry the name from 3 dimensions as they are generalized to higher dimensions:  $n$-cube, $n$-ball whose boundary is an $(n - 1)$-sphere come to mind.